# react-native: cannot access Android permissions with release mode

Tags: react-native, android-permissions

I used React Native 0.59.9 with expo-permissions to get location, notification and camera rolls permissions from mobiles for my app. Everything is OK with iOS and Android in debug mode. With Android release APK, I cannot get those permissions even I enabled manually in the app setting.

I tried to migrate code from expo to pure react-native

gradle file

```
compileSdkVersion 28
defaultConfig {
    applicationId 'com.xxx.android'
    targetSdkVersion 28
    versionCode 18
    versionName '2.40.00'
    ndk {
      abiFilters 'armeabi-v7a', 'x86'
    }
    multiDexEnabled true
      manifestPlaceholders = [
              'appAuthRedirectScheme': 'com.xxxx'
      ]

  }
```

Android Manifest permissions

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

I always get nerver_ask_again result on Android release APK, even it's a fresh app. Everything is ok on debug mode.

Answer (score 1):

copy your all

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

into ###{projectfolder}/android/app/main/AndroidManifest.xml###

Comment: Please format your question better. And also would be helpful if you put a little bit explanation.

Comment: The explanation is that most times you experience the issue because you added the permissions only to the debug AndroidManifest.xml. He referenced in his answer the path to the release AndroidManifest.xml, which will be bundled by react-native to your app release version.